# Not being able to MongoDB through mongojs in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongojs

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mongodb://******:********@********.mlab.com:*****/XXXXXXXX_XXXX', ['XXXX']);

router.get('/tasks', function(req, res, next){
    db.tasks.find(function(err, tasks){
        if(err){
            console.log('connection error!');
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(tasks);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have this simple code in node in which I am trying to connect to Mongo. I believe the process is quite straight-forward and I am following it right. Howver I get Authentication failed error every time. I checked the id password and they are just fine. Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you able to connect using some other client (such as robomongo/mongochef/cli) using those same credentials?

Comment: just fixed it. I realized I was using the Mlab credentials instead of the db user credentials.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/tasks', (req, res)) {
db.tasks.find()
    .then(tasks => res.json(tasks))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err);
});
```

try that.  you had it set up like the get was using a custom middleware component, and you were then passing a function into the .find() call. .find() will get all documents and returns a promise. .then() executes once the promise has been returned, and .catch() executes if .find() had an error.